# AS#3, 3D Modelling Formats AWD, Collada, A3DS

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, 3dsmax, away3d

Here are my specs:

- flash Professional SC5 + Added flash player 11.02 to debugger version "15".
- Away3d 4.0
- 3d MAX 2012
- flex SDK 4.5 or 6

I'm trying to load a simple model with an animation into flash CS5, the problem is not the coding as such its the structure:

away3d flash engine supports AWD, Doom engine 2 & 5 for animation.
3D MAX 2012 does not export any of these formats(I have tried scripts/plugins) seem to be all out dated

So for the life of me I can't work out how to achieve this, I have googled and looked through forums...
Some suggest making my own scripts for max and flash to do this but its way out of my league.

I also tried Alternativa3d the latest and ran into a lot of problems as well so does any one know how can I import a 3d model with animation into flash, as collada is not supported in away 3d 4.0

currently I'm not the only one who is clueless on this matter either, its seems many people have this same issue.

It seems to me Away 3d is just basically advanced morso or unsupported by other tools, such as everything is out-dated, plugins/exporting scripts from 3dmax support/Blender etc. and no support for collada at current which doesn't really leave any available animated model formats.

Comment: I any one has a better straight forward open source suggestion im interested as im only now starting to play with these* im not fixated on any paticular environment or structure...take into account im after an engine that is capable of producing lighting /shadows and all them fancy things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have seem to come up with a work around, simply use an old version of 3dMax 2009-2010
And google for exporting scripts, MD5 exporter there seems to be a few going around but none are compatable with max 2011 ++, Same goes for Blender i think 2.59 was the easiest to work with.

If you find a better solution please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The newest version of Away3D 4 Gold supports Collada (DAE) files.  These support animations, and I believe that the Blender exporter is up to date enough to output one animation per model, or one animation file per animation (rather than all in one) -- I haven't worked with it yet.  But I have gotten the models successfully imported and rendered in Away3D.  Please see [this Away3D forum question](http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/2935/) about loading textures, since the code there works for importing models.  Otherwise, there are now some examples in the Away3D downloads that may be useful.

Comment: I have just ventured back in to flash, Using these updated libs... Still A bit of confusion as there is a lot of out of date informations on these including libs, docs ,source , examples, SDK versions but slowly im sifting through it.

Comment: Yeah, Away Gold has a long way to go to be ready to use.  They never have done a very good job with docs or tuts.  There are some up and coming 3D engines which may start to be good substitutes for Away.  http://flashdaily.net usually has pretty interesting info about recent developments.

Comment: do not use these file types, there expensive Collada (DAE) files.

Comment: I recommend using sea3d libs + away3d, it compresses nice and its its very simple to use